# Perl, extract specific columns

Tags: perl, shell

Please help.

I have two files (file1 and file2). I would like to extract the columns from file2 that have their IDs listed in file1. These are big files, with thousands of columns and lines.

file1

```
Id123B
Id124A
Id125A
```

file2

```
Code  sex  id123B  id127  id125A
```

desired output file:

```
code sex id123B  id125A
```

The following is the code i have tried, but it fails.

```
!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $IN, "file2" or die $!;

my $header = <$IN>;

my %sampleID = map { /(.*?)\t/; $1 => 1 } <$IN>;

close($IN);

open $IN, "file1" or die $!;
$header = <$IN>;
my @samples = split /\t/, $header;
my @cols = grep { exists $sampleID{$samples[$_]} } 0..$#samples;


while(<$IN>){
    chomp;
    my @line = (split /\t/)[@cols]; 

    print join( "\t", @line ), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a hash to map column names to column numbers.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

open my $COLUMNS, '<', shift or die $!;
chomp( my @columns = <$COLUMNS> );

open my $DATA, '<', shift or die $!;
my @header = split /\t/, <$DATA>;
my %column_index;
@column_index{ @header } = 0 .. $#header;

@columns = grep exists $column_index{$_}, @columns;

while (<$DATA>) {
    chomp( my @cells = split /\t/ );
    say join "\t", @cells[ @column_index{ @columns } ];
}
```

Run as `script.pl file1 file2`. Note that you must use exact column names in the file, i.e. I got better results with the following file1:

```
Code
sex
id123B
id124A
id125A
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I just ran it and It is not printing any output. Data format perhaps?

Comment: @El.h Probably, it works for me. Check the column names.